# Migration Alter Table SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to migrate this sentence in SQL Server to Oracle:

```
ALTER TABLE <name table> ADD DEFAULT (NULL) FOR <name column>;
```

I'm beginner in SQL Server and Oracle so I don't know what it means with `DEFAULT (NULL) FOR`.

If you can help me with the migration please and explain the sequence.

Comment: isn't `NULL` the default anyways ?

Comment: I thought the same, but they gave me the code like that.

Comment: by **they** you mean ? It simply doesn't solve any purpose.

Comment: You don't need to alter the table after adding the column to specify null. It will default to null, and you can choose a different default if you wish. Specifying an additional alter to add a null default is superfluous.

Comment: @JacobH Stop making assumptions. The nullability of a column that is created without a specific null/not null directive is determined by a connection setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-null-dflt-on-transact-sql. Either way, it is still nonsense to default a default of null

Comment: @SMor the article you linked specifically states that is the default functionality of the database. Just because there is a setting you can use to disable it does not revoke the fact that it is, in fact, the default. Not only that, you linked a SQL Server article, not Oracle. At least we agree that it is silly to default a default null.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> MODIFY <COLUMN_NAME> DEFAULT NULL;
```

Though the above doesn't make much sense. The sample below tries to make some

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> MODIFY <ANY_DATE_COLUMN_NAME> DEFAULT SYSDATE;
```